# setTargetObjectIds ignore the setTo in Email

Tags: email

Our clients might have multiple Account they are related to but for each account they have a preferred contact email, which is why we stored this preference in the AccountContactRelation.

I am trying to use the setTargetObjectId on the MassEmail message (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_mass.htm) together with a setTo from the base class to deliver to a specific email per AccountContactRelation, however the delivery fails with error:

No Messages were sent. First Error: nullError Code:INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS - The target object's email address "null" is not valid

What is the appropriate way to relate an email to a Contact and still use a specific email instead of the default Contact.Email for delivery?

Answer (score 2):

`setTargetObjectId` is trying to send the email *in addition to* the `setTo` address you specify, which is the default behavior. This is what is causing the error. Use `setTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient(false)` to allow your code to run correctly. Note that you'll also need to use `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage` instead of `Messaging.MassEmailMessage`. These are almost the same in terms of functionality, but SEM is more capable for situations like this.

Comment: Thank you. Will Salesforce keep the relation between the email and the contact it if I do that ?

Comment: @Edmondo1984 Yes, it should be associated to the Contact in their Activity History.